# Retrieve Parse Array of Objects in Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm storying an array of JavaScript key/value objects in a column of type `Array` on Parse like this:

```
[{"1432747073241":1.1},{"1432142558000":3.7}]
```

When I retrieve that column in Swift, I can see the data, but I'm unsure what data type to cast it as:

```
if let data = dashboardObject[graphColumn] as? [AnyObject]{  
  for pair in data{
    println(pair)
  }
}
```

That print yields this in the console (for the first pair):

```
{
  1432747073241 = "1.1";
}
```

I can't seem to cast its contents as a Dictionary `[Int:Double]` and I'm guessing that means this is a string.

How do I parse this data in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: The Dictionary you should parse it to is `[String: AnyObject]`. It seems as if the keys of this dictionary are timestamps which you probably don't know. 
You could iterate through the dictionary like this: `for (key, value) in pair { }`

Comment: Ah, great, thanks! Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that they are time stamps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dictionary you should parse it to is `[String: AnyObject]`. It seems as if the keys of this dictionary are timestamps which you probably don't know. You could iterate through the dictionary like this:

```
for (key, value) in pair {
  // do what you want in here with the value and/or the key 
}
```